# Change grid layout at runtime

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a grid with the following row definitions...

```
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

When the user presses a button, how do I remove the bottom two rows and have the top row (including the view within it) stretch to the bottom of the grid?

I kept all the rows and did this...

```
mainGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
mainGrid.ForceLayout();
```

I would like to animate the change in height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

**The grid**

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 x:Name="stkOne" 
                 BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 x:Name="stkTwo" 
                 BackgroundColor="Green"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 x:Name="stkThree" 
                 BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
    <Button Text="Expand One"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            Command="ExpandCommand"/>
</Grid>
```

**The code behind**

```
// Create the command and set it up to execute this method:
void ExecuteExpand()
{
    stkTwo.IsVisible=false;
    stkThree.IsVisible=false;
    Grid.SetRowSpan(stkOne, 3);
    grid.ForceLayout();
}
```

I'm not sure if it will work as you need, but make a try.

Comment: I actually only updated the height of the bottom row. but `ForceLayout` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to animate it?

Comment: Yes, but in this case we will need to see the code and know what effect you desire

Comment: Try to use the `LayoutTo` method

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work given that it requires a "bounds".

Comment: It's just the layout limits, like a rectangle. You can use something like `Rectangle gridBounds = grid.Bounds;` and then `stkOne.LayoutTo(gridBounds);`

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference. I set the duration to ten seconds and it still snaps both ways.